# 3D Collision help

Tags: xna, c#, collision-detection, heightmap, jiglibx

I'm having difficulties with my project. I'm quite new in XNA. Anyway, I'm trying to make 3D game and I'm already stuck on one basic thing. I have terrain made from a heightmap, and an avatar model. I want to set up some collisions for game so the player won't go through the ground. But I just don't know how to detect collisions for so complex an object. I could just make a simple box collision for my avatar, but what about the ground?

I already implemented the JigLibX physics engine in my project and I know that I can make a collision map with heightmap, but I can't find any tutorials or help with this. So how can I set proper collision for complex objects? How can I detect heightmap collisions in JigLibX? Just some links to tutorials would be enough.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: unless you need pixel-perfect collisions why cant you put you "avatar" into a simplified bounding volume. though I would suggest a sphere over a box considering that a box is just a simple polyhedral, and even with fast algorithms you want to avoid polyhedrals if possible. and shouldn't this info be in the documentation of the engine?

Comment: What's wrong with polyhedrals?

Comment: I think gardian meant that with a polyhedral you'd have more area in contact with the terrain at all times (a flat edge, usually), which, depending on the algorithm, could be slower than having more of a concentrated point with a sphere (since it's round). Although, I don't really think that's the case usually. Regardless, a sphere is usually more accurate for 3D objects anyway.

Answer (score 1):

I suggest you take a look at the official JigLibX wiki, located [over here.](http://jiglibx.wikidot.com)

Specifically, you may want to take a look at the quickstart guide from the wiki, located [here.](http://jiglibx.wikidot.com/quickstart)

There are plenty of articles on the wiki that should help you out.  Otherwise, you might want to check out their [forums](http://jiglibx.wikidot.com/forum%3astart) for related posts.

Comment: I already did that before I even asked, but thanks anyway.

Comment: Oh, I'm sorry.  Perhaps you should put that in your original question, then.  The wiki is kind of *the* de facto source of JigLibX info, so that'd be important to note in your question.